# Python sqlite data groupby

Tags: python, sqlite

I use this code:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Day = 'S' AND Booked = 'N' AND Disabled = 'Y'")
for number, rows in groupby(cur, key=lambda r: r[0][0]):
    print 'Disabled seats available : ', ', '.join([r[0] for r in rows])
```

It Groups the data together to give the following answer:

```
Disabled seats available :  A1, A14
Disabled seats available :  B1, B16
Disabled seats available :  C1, C17
Disabled seats available :  D1, D19
Disabled seats available :  E1, E20
Disabled seats available :  F1, F20
Disabled seats available :  G1, G19
Disabled seats available :  H1, H19
Disabled seats available :  J1, J19
Disabled seats available :  K1, K19
Disabled seats available :  L1, L15
```

But i want the seats to be displayed in the following manner:

```
Disabled seats available: A1,A14,B1,B16
```

Like with no lines inbetween each one?

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Then why use groupby in the first place?

Comment: because i have a whole other section that doesnt display disabled seats where in which groupby is actually useful.

Comment: I know, you based that on my answer, but in this case, there is no need to group your seats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the `groupby` call, and just use the rows from your cursor directly:

```
print 'Disabled seats available : ', ', '.join([r[0] for r in cur])
```